# Unable to use GroupedListView with Firebase stream

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, grouped-list

We are using the GroupedListView package which for the most part seems to be serve what we need in our application. The issue occurs when adding a new record to the Stream that the GroupedListView complains that Bad State: Stream has already been listened to.

```
Widget buildMessages(convoId) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      key: widget.key,
      stream: DatabaseService.getChatMessages(convoId),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          message = snapshot.data!.docs;
          return GroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
            reverse: true,
            elements: message,
            groupBy: (element) =>
                DateFormat('yMMdd').format(element['timestamp'].toDate()),
            order: GroupedListOrder.DESC,
            groupSeparatorBuilder: _createGroupHeader,
            itemBuilder: (context, dynamic element) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                child: _buildMessage(element)),
            controller: listScrollController,
          );
        } else {
          return const SizedBox();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _createGroupHeader(element) {
    if (isToday(DateTime.parse(element))) {
      return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          'Today'.toUpperCase(),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium!,
        ),
      );
    }
    if (isYesterday(DateTime.parse(element))) {
      return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          'Yesterday'.toUpperCase(),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium!,
        ),
      );
    }
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Text(
        DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.parse(element)).toUpperCase(),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium!,
      ),
    );
  }
```